# Detect Endianness with CMake

Tags: cmake, endianness

My library needs to read-in big-endian integers (4-bytes) and convert them to the endian order of the host for processing.  While on *nix `ntohl` has worked a treat under Windows use of `ntohl` requires the use of `Ws2_32.dll` (Winsock).

Such a dependency is one which I would rather eliminate.  The simplest way to do this appears to be to write my own endian-swapping function (a trivial exercise, considering performance is not a real concern).  However, this requires a way to determine the endianness of the system my library is being compiled on (so I can `#ifdef` out the swapping function on big endian systems).

As there appears to be no standard preprocessor definition for endianness it appears as if it is necessary to determine it using my build system (cmake).  What is the best means of doing this?  (I am weary of 'compile a test file and see' type solutions as they would appear to inhibit cross-compiling.)

Comment: Remark: CMake actually has reasonable support for cross-compilation. For checks that require running a test program, it builds the test program and then waits for you to set cache variables to the correct result. See http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling . Have an upvote for caring about cross compilation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edited: I see that `cmake` has a `TestBigEndian.cmake` script, but that does a compilation and test run to see if the system is Big Endian or not, which is not what you want to do.

You can check for the system's endianness in your own program with a function like this.

```
bool isLittleEndian()
{
    short int number = 0x1;
    char *numPtr = (char*)&number;
    return (numPtr[0] == 1);
}
```

Basically create an integer, and read its first byte (least significant byte). If that byte is 1, then the system is little endian, otherwise it's big endian.

However this doesn't allow you to determine endianness until runtime.

If you want compilation time determination of system endianness, I do not see much alternative aside from the 'building a test program and then compile my real program' a la `cmake`, or doing exhaustive checks for specific macros defined by compilers, e.g. `__BIG_ENDIAN__` on GCC 4.x.

**UPDATED** You might want to take a look at Boost's own `endian.hpp` as an example, too.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/detail/endian.hpp

Comment: "However this doesn't allow you to determine endianness until runtime."
- You can do something like this, and it should be evaluated at compile time:
const bool g_isLittleEndian=isLittleEndian();

Comment: @darklon `const` variable is not strictly evaluated at compile time. It can and will be evaluated at runtime since `isLittleEndian()` uses variables. To make it strictly evaluated at compile time, keyword `constexpr` or a template metaprogramming technique should be used. (The reason why I thought `const bool g_isLittleEndian=isLittleEndian();` will be evaluated at runtime is because `(char*)(& number)` is not a constant expression. That's what GCC says when you declare `numPtr` as `constexpr`)

Comment: for more info on what can be declared a `constexpr`, see [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Answer (score 15):

Also this CMake function could do it, http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/TestBigEndian.html

```
include (TestBigEndian)
TEST_BIG_ENDIAN(IS_BIG_ENDIAN)
if(IS_BIG_ENDIAN)
 message(STATUS "BIG_ENDIAN")
else()
 message(STATUS "LITTLE_ENDIAN")
endif()
```

I think that is supported only from CMake 3.0

Comment: A note: since CMake 3.20, `TestBigEndian` is deprecated and `CMAKE_<LANG>_BYTE_ORDER` is introduced, as its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/module/TestBigEndian.html) says.